# SQL query to substitute a value of a column based on the value in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in SQL Server which has Data as follows:

```
Costing_ID CostingName CostingNumber CostingNumberSuffix StartDate
1          Test        1234                              2014-04-01
2          Test 2      1234          AA                  2014-04-06
3          Test 3      5668                              2014-04-09
4          Test 4      1234          AB                  2014-04-14
```

I need to produce a view which returns all the rows, but substitutes the StartDate of items where CostingNumberSuffix is not empty with the StartDate of the corresponding CostingNumber which is empty.

So my query should return the following:

```
   Costing_ID CostingName CostingNumber CostingNumberSuffix StartDate
    1          Test        1234                              2014-04-01
    2          Test 2      1234          AA                  2014-04-01
    3          Test 3      5668                              2014-04-09
    4          Test 4      1234          AB                  2014-04-01
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What date would you put in for test 3?

Comment: Test 3 has its own CostingNumber and no suffix, so it would keep it's StartDate. Were I to have a test 6 with CostingNumber 5668 and Suffix ZZ, it would get StartDate of Test 3  etc. There will only ever be a single record on each CostingNumber which has no suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query. I haven't tested it, but you get the idea:

```
SELECT
    Costing_ID,
    CostingName,
    CostingNumber,
    CostingNumberSuffix,
    CASE
        WHEN CostingNumberSuffix != ''
            THEN (SELECT s.StartDate FROM table s WHERE s.CostingNumber = t.CostNumber and s.CostNumberSuffix = '')
        ELSE
            StartDate
    END 
FROM table t
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012:

```
select Costing_ID, CostingName, CostingNumber, CostingNumberSuffix,
first_value(StartDate) over (partition by CostingNumber order by CostingNumberSuffix
    rows unbounded preceding) as StartDate
from Costing
order by Costing_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a SQL query to substitute a value of a column based on the value in another:

```
select t1.Costing_ID, t1.CostingName, t1.CostingNumber,
  t1.CostingNumberSuffix,
  coalesce (t2.StartDate, t1.StartDate)
from <table name> t1
left join (select * from <table name> where CostingNumberSuffix = '') t2
on t1.costingnumber = t2.costingnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a Common Table Expression (A.k.a CTE). The CTE finds the StartDate of the items where CostingNumberSuffix is empty.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CostingNumber, StartDate
    FROM <tablename>
    WHERE CostingNumberSuffix IS NULL
)
SELECT
    T.Costing_ID,
    T.CostingName,
    T.CostingNumber,
    T.CostingNumberSuffix,
    ISNULL(CTE.StartDate, T.StartDate) AS StartDate
FROM <tablename> T
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE
ON T.CostingNumber = CTE.CostingNumber
```